# What are the details for Strike Team Mission "traits"?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

This Strike Team mission has 3 Traits that are modifiers for this particular mission:

[image: traits]

Is there anywhere that lists the Traits and their effects, in-game or otherwise? E.g. what does "No Room For Error" actually mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer I can give you on this is to refer you to the Mass Effect Wiki.

The data there is updated as new information is discovered.

Here is the link to the Strike Team page : https://masseffectandromeda.gamepedia.com/Strike_team

Info as at 6 April 2017

Positive

- Bloodthirsty: +10 to Effectiveness with Enemies Everywhere
- Daring: +10 to Effectiveness with High-Risk, High-Reward
- Elite: +5 to Effectiveness
- Fearless: +10 to Effectiveness with Scary
- Grizzled    Veteran: +5 to Effectiveness
- Heroic: +10 to Effectiveness with We Need a Hero
- Kett Specialist: +10 to Effectiveness with Kett
- Lucky: +5 to Effectiveness
- Nighttime Operator +10 to Effectiveness with Nighttime Missions
- Outlaw Specialist: +10 to Effectiveness with Outlaw
- Precise: +10 to Effectiveness with No Room For Error
- Remnant Specialist: +10 to Effectiveness with Remnant
- Rugged: +10 to Effectiveness during Poor Weather Conditions
- Skirmisher: +5 to Effectiveness
- Stealthy: +10 to Effectiveness with Silent and Deadly
- Tactician: +5 to Effectiveness
- Tough: +5 to Effectiveness
- Virtuous: +10 to Effectiveness with Bribe Attempt

Negative

- Berserker: -10 to Effectiveness with Enemies Everywhere
- Corruptible: -10 to Effectiveness with Bribe Attempt
- Cowardly: -10 Effectiveness with Scary
- Hero Complex: -10 to Effectiveness with We Need a Hero
- Kett Hysteria: -10 to Effectiveness with Kett
- Nightblind: -10 to Effectiveness during night missions
- Outlaw Hysteria: -10 to Effectiveness with Outlaw
- Raucous: -10 to Effectiveness with Silent and Deadly
- Remnant Hysteria: -10 to Effectiveness with Remnant
- Slow Reflexes -5 to Effectiveness
- Timid: -10 to Effectiveness with High Risk, High Reward
- Unlucky: -5 to Effectiveness
- Xenophobe: -10 to Effectiveness with Alien Presence

Comment: thanks for link and list, at time of posting i did not know if this info was available in-game or not, and that list did not exist (or at least i couldnt find it!). Now that i understand how all this works, i realize you dont really need info for a trait you dont have, and if you have it, there is an explanation in your teams info section.  Very interesting tp see the other traits though, i did not realize there were some that just inherently give benefits without needing a companion trait on the mission

Answer (score 6):

So far as I can tell, and this is limited info, if you match mission traits with a comparable positive trait of the strike team then you get a bonus for chance to succeed in completing the mission successfully.  If you have a negative trait that matches with the mission trait it will negatively affect your chance to succeed.  You get positive traits occasionally when you beat a mission, and negative traits occasionally when you fail a mission.  So if you have the fearless trait on your team and the mission is scary then you get a bonus to win.  I don't know what the negative trait is, haven't seen it yet.  I'm sure eventually there will be a compilation of the traits made here soon.

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer the question, the traits on strike team missions don't mean anything by themselves.

For example, "Scary" doesn't do *anything* unless the strike team attempting the mission has an associated trait or piece of equipment. If they have Fearless, then they get +10 effectiveness, if they have Cowardly they -10.

[Gamepedia has an in-progress list](http://masseffectandromeda.gamepedia.com/Strike_team) of these strike team traits, as [Kitiara pointed out](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/305233/108003). That page also lists known equipment, some of which correspond to mission traits.

Answer (score 0):

I did read somewhere that No Room for Error matches up with the team trait "precision"

I've tried to find a list someone has started but haven't had luck.

Comment: There's a list in another answer here now, if you're still interested.